# In tkinter, i'm creating a treeview that has to many columns to fit my frame, and my horizontal scrollbar doesn't work well

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

So basicaly, i'm using tkinter treeview, with a widget technique, so I don't use "self" argument right away, i use a widget append function, I hope you'll still be able to help me !

So here's my code :
#Sorry for the long code sample !
#Basicaly here I initialize my Treeview (Tableau), and set the columns and headings

```
    Tableau=ttk.Treeview(Bloc_TAB)
Tableau['columns']=('Distance','Conso H2 (kg)','Conso H2 (kg/100km)','DoD Max', 'SOC Final (v=0)',
                            'Temps de Parcours v=0 (s)','Conso H2 v=0','SOC final (%)','Temps Parcours (s)','Eelec_TractionChain_Recup',
                            'Eelec_DCDCBus1500_Recup','E_Battery_Recup','E_Aux_Recup','E_DCDC_Losses_Recup','E_Losses_Bus_Recup','E_BrResistor_Losses_Recup',
                            'E_FC [kWh]','E_Battery [kWh]','E_Aux [kWh]','E_FCDC_Losses [kWh]','E_DCDC_Losses [kWh]','E_Losses_Bus [kWh]',
                            'E_BrResistor_Losses [kWh]','SOC max  (%)','SOC min  (%)','Pmin bat','Pmax bat','Eusable','P FC mean (kW)')
    
    
   
    Tableau.column("#0", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Distance", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Conso H2 (kg)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Conso H2 (kg/100km)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("DoD Max", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("SOC Final (v=0)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Temps de Parcours v=0 (s)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Conso H2 v=0", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("SOC final (%)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Temps Parcours (s)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Eelec_TractionChain_Recup", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Eelec_DCDCBus1500_Recup", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_Battery_Recup", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_Aux_Recup", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_DCDC_Losses_Recup", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_Losses_Bus_Recup", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_BrResistor_Losses_Recup", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_FC [kWh]", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_Battery [kWh]", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_Aux [kWh]", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_FCDC_Losses [kWh]", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_DCDC_Losses [kWh]", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_Losses_Bus [kWh]", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("E_BrResistor_Losses [kWh]", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("SOC max  (%)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("SOC min  (%)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Pmin bat", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Pmax bat", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("Eusable", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
    Tableau.column("P FC mean (kW)", minwidth=120,stretch=True)
            
   
    Tableau.heading("#0",text="Mission")
    Tableau.heading("Distance",text="Distance")
    Tableau.heading("Conso H2 (kg)",text="Conso H2 (kg)")
    Tableau.heading("Conso H2 (kg/100km)",text="Conso H2 (kg/100km)")
    Tableau.heading("DoD Max",text="DoD Max")
    Tableau.heading("SOC Final (v=0)",text="SOC Final (v=0)")
    Tableau.heading("Temps de Parcours v=0 (s)",text="Temps de Parcours v=0 (s)")
    Tableau.heading("Conso H2 v=0",text="Conso H2 v=0")
    Tableau.heading("SOC final (%)",text="SOC final (%)")
    Tableau.heading("Temps Parcours (s)",text="Temps Parcours (s)")
    Tableau.heading("Eelec_TractionChain_Recup",text="Eelec_TractionChain_Recup")
    Tableau.heading("Eelec_DCDCBus1500_Recup",text="EeDC_recup")
    Tableau.heading("E_Battery_Recup",text="E_Battery_Recup")
    Tableau.heading("E_Aux_Recup",text="E_Aux_Recup")
    Tableau.heading("E_DCDC_Losses_Recup",text="E_DCDC_Losses_Recup")
    Tableau.heading("E_Losses_Bus_Recup",text="E_Losses_Bus_Recup")
    Tableau.heading("E_BrResistor_Losses_Recup",text="E_BrResistor_Losses_Recup")        
    Tableau.heading("E_FC [kWh]",text="E_FC [kWh]")
    Tableau.heading("E_Battery [kWh]",text="E_Battery [kWh]")
    Tableau.heading("E_Aux [kWh]",text="E_Aux [kWh]")
    Tableau.heading("E_FCDC_Losses [kWh]",text="E_FCDC_Losses [kWh]")
    Tableau.heading("E_DCDC_Losses [kWh]",text="E_DCDC_Losses [kWh]")
    Tableau.heading("E_Losses_Bus [kWh]",text="E_Losses_Bus [kWh]")
    Tableau.heading("E_BrResistor_Losses [kWh]",text="E_BrResistor_Losses [kWh]")
    Tableau.heading("SOC max  (%)",text="SOC max  (%)")
    Tableau.heading("SOC min  (%)",text="SOC min  (%)")
    Tableau.heading("Pmin bat",text="Pmin bat")
    Tableau.heading("Pmax bat",text="Pmax bat")
    Tableau.heading("Eusable",text="Eusable")
    Tableau.heading("P FC mean (kW)",text="P FC mean (kW)")
```

Next, I set the parameters for my treeview, initialize my scrollbar and link it to my treeview

```
    parametre_Tab={"row": 0,"column":0,"pady":(5,0),"sticky":"W"}
Scrollbar_X_1 = ttk.Scrollbar(Bloc_TAB, orient=HORIZONTAL)
parametre_Scrollbar_X_1 = {"row": 2, "column" : 0, "sticky":"we"}
int_TAB.widget.append((Scrollbar_X_1, parametre_Scrollbar_X_1))  
Scrollbar_X_1.configure(command=Tableau.xview)  
int_TAB.widget.append((Tableau,parametre_Tab))
```

When i run it it does this :

[My Treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrA22.png)

But I read every question, every answer about this kind of issue, but none of them will do the trick :(

Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: You created `Scrollbar_X_1`, but used `Scrollbar_Y_1` in `Tableau.configure(yscrollcommand=...)`.

Comment: Yeah sorry i'm goign to edit that, but it's a mistake of copy/paste, i actualy use both, one in y and one in x

Comment: Try adding `Tableau.configure(xscrollcommand=Scrollbar_X_1.set)` and `Bloc_TAB.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Comment: I'll try but do you think i should add it before creating the Treeview, after, of even after appending it as a widget ?